# Create a custom error message which includes data from another property

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my view model I have an object with the following property:

```
[Display(Name = "Fiscal Year")]
[ValidFiscalYear(FiscalYear = "FiscalYear", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid fiscal year.")]
public int FiscalYear { get; set; }
```

The property has an attribute, `ValidFiscalYear`, that has a string parameter named `FiscalYear`. I'm using this parameter to get the value of another model property named `FiscalYear`. In turn, this property is used to determine validation.

Here is the `FiscalYear` property in the view model:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "FiscalYear")]
public int FiscalYear { get; set; }
```

Here is the attribute:

```
public sealed class ValidFiscalYearAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable 
{
    public string FiscalYear { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        var currentFiscalYearString = HttpContext.Current.Request[FiscalYear];
        var currentFiscalYear = int.Parse(currentFiscalYearString);
        var fiscalYear = (int)value;
        return fiscalYear >= currentFiscalYear && fiscalYear <= currentFiscalYear + 10;
    }
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        return new ModelClientValidationRule[] { new ModelClientValidationRule 
        { 
            ValidationType = "fiscalyear", 
            ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessage }
        };
    }
}
```

and here is my jQuery on the client side:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('fiscalyear', function (value, element, params) {
    var currentFiscalYear = $("#FiscalYear").val();
    return (value >= currentFiscalYear && value <= +currentFiscalYear + 10);
}, '');

jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('fiscalyear', {}, function (options) {
    options.rules['fiscalyear'] = true;
    options.messages['fiscalyear'] = options.message;
});
```

So, everything works as it should but I need to create a custom error message. My question is how can create an error message, on both the client and server sides, that reads,

`Fiscal Year must be between **currentFiscalYear** and **currentFiscalYear + 10**.`

The `currentFiscalYear` parts are acting as variables.

I want to use the `currentFiscalYear` variable from the attribute class in the error message. Is this possible

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom error message by setting the `ErrorMessage` property.

```
public sealed class ValidFiscalYearAttribute : ...
{
    public ValidFiscalYearAttribute()
    {
        ErrorMessage = "My custom message";
    }
    ...
}
```

Your custom validator inherits this property.

Comment: Could I use a use a property value from the view model in that custom error message? And then could I use that same error message on the client side?

Comment: I'm not sure how I can use this to help my situation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass "current fiscal year" from the server to the client because only server knows that value. You can use the following syntax to get to extra values passed from server.

```
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("fiscalyear", ["currentfiscalyear"], function (options) {
    options.rules["fiscalyear"] = options.params.currentfiscalyear;
    options.messages["fiscalyear"] = options.message;
    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse();
});

jQuery.validator.addMethod('fiscalyear', function (value, element, param) {
    var currentFiscalYear = parseInt(param);
    return (value >= currentFiscalYear && value <= currentFiscalYear + 10);
});
```

And here is how you can send the "current fiscal year" value from the server and also a proper error message:

```
public sealed class ValidFiscalYearAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable 
{
    public ValidFiscalYearAttribute() : base("Fiscal Year must be between {0} and {1}.")
    { 

    }

    public string FiscalYear { get; set; }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        var currentFiscalYearString = HttpContext.Current.Request[FiscalYear];
        var currentFiscalYear = int.Parse(currentFiscalYearString);  
        return string.Format(ErrorMessageString, currentFiscalYear, currentFiscalYear + 10);
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // You should not check for null but should not return an error as return error for null should be the responsibility of the Required attribute
        if(value == null) return null;

        var currentFiscalYearString = HttpContext.Current.Request[FiscalYear];
        var currentFiscalYear = int.Parse(currentFiscalYearString);            
        var fiscalYear = (int)value;
        var valid = fiscalYear >= currentFiscalYear && fiscalYear <= currentFiscalYear + 10;

        if (!valid)
        {
            var message = FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName);
            return new ValidationResult(message);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var currentFiscalYearString = HttpContext.Current.Request[FiscalYear];
        var currentFiscalYear = int.Parse(currentFiscalYearString);  
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
        rule.ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName());
        rule.ValidationType = "fiscalyear";
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("currentfiscalyear", currentFiscalYear);
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

As you can see that there are many moving parts. I have not tested this code and typed most of this in the browser. So let me know if you find that something is not working properly.

Comment: For some reason the string property `FiscalYear` stays null, when it should receive the string "FiscalYear" from `[ValidFiscalYear(FiscalYear = "FiscalYear")]`. So when `HttpContext` request executes it has nothing to look for. I hard coded the string "FiscalYear" in the request and it was able to find the Fiscal Year value.

Comment: What exactly is FiscalYear? is it the value that the user is setting on the web page? If that's the case, you do not have to get it like that. the "value" parameter for the IsValid method provides you with the value. I actually thought that the FiscalYear is something that the server already knows. Can you elaborate some more about the data flow here?

Comment: FiscalYear is another property in the view model. The value is set by the controller at run time. It is pulled from the database. The OP has been edited to included it

Comment: in the code sample, you have a property named FiscalYear on which you have applied the ValidFiscalYearAttribute. If that is the property value you are trying to get hold of, you can do that in the IsValid method by using the param "value". Can you confirm if "value" has indeed been set? In that case, you don't even need a "FiscalYear" property in the attribute

Comment: It's confusing because there are two properties with the same name--one is the property of another object. Yes, I am trying to get a hold of the property with the `ValidFiscalYearAttribute`, but I am using the value of the other `FiscalYear` attribute to validate and create the error message. The second `FiscalYear` property and `currentFiscalYear` variable hold the same value.

Comment: Well, I think the naming needs to be clear as this is very confusing. Also, you can simply get hold of the current fiscal year , you can simply do it in the `ValidFiscalYearAttribute` and compare that to the current value. Wouldn't that be simpler and easier?

Comment: This is code I inherited. Also, I am getting `currentFiscalYear` in the attribute: `var currentFiscalYearString = HttpContext.Current.Request[FiscalYear];`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68158/discussion-between-imran-rashid-and-navig8tr).